# Round datetime64 array to nearest second

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, rounding

I have an array of type datetime64[ns]. Each element looks something like `'2019-08-30T14:02:03.684000000'`. How do I round the values to the nearest second such that I would obtain `'2019-08-30T14:02:04'` in this example?

I know I can truncate the values by

```py
t = t.astype('datetime64[s]')
```

but I specifically need to round the values and not truncate them. And the numpy 'round' function doesn't seem to like the datetime64[ns] data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by converting np.datetime64 to datetime.datetime.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt64 = np.datetime64('2019-08-30T14:02:03.684000000')

# np to datetime object
ts = (dt64 - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)

# Rounding
if dt.microsecond/1000000 > 0.5:
  date = (dt + timedelta(seconds=1)).replace(microsecond=0)
else:
  date = dt.replace(microsecond=0)

# Datetime to np 
date_rounded = np.datetime64(date).astype('datetime64[s]')
```

Output:

> numpy.datetime64('2019-08-30T14:02:04')

Answer (score 0):

Another handy utility for rounding datetime64 by specified interval ('accuracy'):

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Union
import numpy as np

UNIX_T0 = np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00')

def round_t64(time: Union[np.datetime64, datetime], dt: Union[np.timedelta64, int]):
    """
    Round timestamp by dt
    """
    if isinstance(dt, int):
        dt = np.timedelta64(dt, 's')

    if isinstance(time, datetime):
        time = np.datetime64(time)

    return time - (time - UNIX_T0) % dt
```

And use case:

```
# floor to 1 sec
round_t64(np.datetime64(datetime.now()), np.timedelta64(1, 's'))

# ceil to 1 sec
round_t64(np.datetime64(datetime.now()), -np.timedelta64(1, 's'))

# floor to 5 min
round_t64(np.datetime64(datetime.now()), np.timedelta64(5, 'm'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) function from the [.dt-accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors):

```py
import pandas as pd
t = pd.Series(['2019-08-30T14:02:03.684000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
# 0   2019-08-30 14:02:03.684
# dtype: datetime64[ns]

t.dt.round('s')
# 0   2019-08-30 14:02:04
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```